# Sending and receiving data from PC via UART to STM32 problem

Tags: c, qt, uart

I try to send a (multiple data rows) hex-Data from PC to STM32 using UART connection.

Word looks like:

```
FF18E2054605A11661EE
FF4353454605A11661EE
FF18E2564645A11661EE
FF18E2054667876861EE
...
```

(0xFF and 0xEE are start and stop bytes)

If I sending it via CuteCom console, it works great (I receive a data and save it to two-dimensional array)

If I'm using a QT Programm (that schould make the same aim) its not work, please help to find a bug!

(PC side) QT:

```
static uint16_t m1 = 0;
static uint16_t m2 = 0;
static uint16_t m3 = 0;
static uint16_t m4 = 0;

static QByteArray hextest;

if(lines.at(i).contains(",")){
    while(lines.at(i+j) != "\n"){
        QStringList speed_chunks = lines.at(i+j).split(",");
        uart = speed_chunks.at(2)+speed_chunks.at(3)+speed_chunks.at(4)+speed_chunks.at(5) +"\0";

        m1 = speed_chunks.at(2).toInt();
        m2 = speed_chunks.at(3).toInt();
        m3 = speed_chunks.at(4).toInt();
        m4 = speed_chunks.at(5).toInt();

        hextest.resize(8);

        hextest[0]=255;
        hextest[1]=m1>>8;
        hextest[2]=m1;
        hextest[3]=m2>>8;
        hextest[4]=m2;
        hextest[5]=m3>>8;
        hextest[6]=m3;
        hextest[6]=m4>>8;
        hextest[8]=m4;
        hextest[9]=238;

        qDebug()<< uart;
        qDebug()<< hextest.toHex();

        m_serial.write(hextest.toHex());
        m_serial.waitForBytesWritten(1000);
        QThread::usleep(2000000);

        j++;
    }
    i += j;
}
```

(STM32 side) C-code:

```
void USART2_IRQHandler() {

    if (USART_GetITStatus(USART2, USART_IT_RXNE) == SET) {          //Checks whether the specified USART interrupt has occurred
        USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART2, USART_IT_RXNE);             //Clears the USART2 interrupt pending bits
        static int string_cnt = 0;                                  //Initialisation of string counter
        char uart_input = USART2->DR;                               //Initialisation a char variable with USART Data register

        if (uart_input == 0xff) {                                   //If a string = 0xff > first Letter
            string_cnt = 0;                                         //String_cnt reset
        }

        if (string_cnt < 10) {                              //If string_cnt < 10 letters ->
            received_str[string_cnt++] = uart_input;                //receive next letter
        }
        if (string_cnt >= 10 && received_str[0] == 0xff && received_str[9] == 0xee) {   //If string_cnt >= 10 units and first unit = 0xff & last = 0xee ->
            receive_done_flag = TRUE;                               //receive_done_flag = true
        }
    }
}

while(h<5000){

if (receive_done_flag == TRUE){
    testarrays[0][h]=((uint16_t)received_str[1] << 8) | received_str[2];
    testarrays[1][h]=((uint16_t)received_str[3] << 8) | received_str[4];
    testarrays[2][h]=((uint16_t)received_str[5] << 8) | received_str[6];
    testarrays[3][h]=((uint16_t)received_str[7] << 8) | received_str[8];

    h++;

    receive_done_flag=FALSE;
}
```

So, `testarrays[0][x]` for different x hex data becomes a same value (received_str get no new data)

Thank you!

P.S. What about formatting while using chrome? Strg+K dont work anymore of course of Chrome-shortcut =(

Comment: I see allready a part of problem: ```if (string_cnt >= 10 && received_str[0] == 0xff && received_str[9] == 0xee) {
    receive_done_flag = TRUE;        
}```
UART receive somethink and interrupt will activated -> and this if-function will still TRUE (string_cnt will not setting to 0, received_str[0] is still 0xff and received_str[9] is still 0xee)

Comment: maybe I'm sending wrong a hex-Values from QT-Creator? ```m_serial.write(hextest.toHex());
```

Comment: You need to determine if you're sending hex (e.g. text), or raw binary data. I think you're sending the latter, but the code talks about the former. Very confusing. Also, the text-to-binary conversion code makes no sense.

Comment: You have `hextest[6] = ...` twice. Also, why are you writing `hextest.toHex()` to your port, as it seems you are trying to receive binary data on your STM32 side.

Comment: @unwind yeah, I want to reduce a transmitted data, of course of this I want send a hex values (its wrong thinking?) 
Text to binary?  You want to say that .toHex make a text from int values? How can I transmit a raw values?

Comment: @thuga hextest[6] = yaeh thanks, it was just tipping misstake) Yes, I want to receive a hex values and save this on STM32 (lot of data) and I want to save a memory.

Comment: I think I missunderstood a basic principle - if I'm sending a value: ex. 1500
```serial.write(1500);    // decimal
serial.write(0x05 DC);  // hexadecimal ```
is the same ammout of Bytes (two bytes)? Right?

Comment: @Fracture Consider the difference between `const uint8_t data1[] = { 100, 200 };` and `const uint8_t data2[] = { 0x64, 0xc8 }`. These two arrays are exactly equal, since the base ("hex" is a base, it's short for hexadecimal i.e. base 16) is just a matter of how you *print* the number as text in the source code. That would be, for this example, `const char data3[] = "64c8"`. The data is two bytes, the hex is four since four hexadecimal digits are involved. You want to send/receive binary, not hex.

Comment: `QByteArray::toHex` returns a hexadecimal representation of your data in a string format. If you want to send raw values, just send your byte array as it is.

Comment: @unwind Thank you, yes I understand now!

Comment: @Fracture Great. My comment above needs editing, but it's too late. :/

Comment: @thuga yes, thanks, it was only for qDebug() usefull (to see a hex values) - i will send a binary data!